# How to make a android app to display questions paper from various stream?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make an app which displays all previous year question papers.... now the problem is...My university has 8 streams to choose and each stream has 8 semesters and each semester has 5 subjects and I want to display papers for each subject when user click on subject name.

Example:-CSE
                     ---Semester 2
                                ---Subject name
                                                    ----year

Now the problem is... for 8 stream I have to make 8 activities and each stream have 8 semester means again 8 activities for each stream and each semester has 5 subjects so I have to make again 40 activities for each stream and each activity hold various subjects.

So is there any simple way to display all the papers with minimum number of activities.

I am new in programming world so please suggest me simple solution for the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your progress. What have you tried so far? what is the problem you have?

Comment: You don't need to use activities for that. You can use fragments, which can be reused again and again. If you want more details regarding fragments, you can find it here.. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html                  Also when posting a question, try to put some more details by posting some code. Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution to the above stated problem is static. Try creating a dynamic app wherein you have only one activity for showing the paper. You can pass in the subject code and semester code to the activity when it is created. You can then use that information to fetch the papers that you want to display in that activity from the database or something.

What I mean to say is that, you can have one activity named main_activity wherein you make the user to select the branch and the semester and the subject. Then you can have a button which can be clicked to launch a new activity which shows the paper of the subject that the user selected.

When programming the show papers button, you can use intent to change the activity and can pass some variables to the activity that is going to be created. Something like this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowPapers.class);
intent.putExtra("Subject_code","CE501");
startActivity(intent);
```

For show papers activity you can use -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String subject_code=intent.getStringExtra("Subject_code");
```

Once you have the subject_code, you can fetch the papers for that subject code from the database.

Hope this helps! :)